# How to align lines exceeding?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I am trying to write proceeding paper. But I have lines exceeding. How to align the lines exceeding?

Example:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IAENGtran} 
    \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
    \usepackage{upgreek} 
    \usepackage{amssymb} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\begin{document}
Thomas Edison was born on 11 February 1847. He was one of the outstanding geniuses of technology and he obtained patents for more than one thousand inventions including the electric light bulb, the record player and an early type of film projector. He also created the world's first industrial research laboratory.

He was born in Milan, Ohio and he was always an inquisitive boy. By the time he was 10 he had set up a small chemical laboratory in his house after his mother had shown him a science book. He soon became fascinated with electrical currents and it remained the main interest of his life.

In 1869, he borrowed a small amount of money and became a freelance inventor. In the same summer, there was a crisis in the New York financial district called Wall Street when the new telegraphic gold-price indicator broke down. Edison was called in to repair it and he did it so well that he was given a job as supervisor with the Western Union Telegraph Company. They later commissioned him to improve the Wall Street stock ticker that was just coming into use. He did so and produced the Edison Universal Stock Printer, which immediately brought him a fortune of $40,000. With this money, he set up as a manufacturer in order to produce electrical machines.

    \begin{equation}

2000000x+30000000000y-6000000000000z=400000000000000
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use one of the `split`, `aligned`, `alignedat` or `multlined` environments.

Comment: Is the `IAENGtran` document class available somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: http://www.iaeng.org/WCE2017/publications.html#templates

Comment: Unrelated to what you are asking (@Bernard has already answered), but remember that you can never include an empty line inside an `equation` environment.  Also, change `$40,000` to `\$\,40,000`.